# how to format cells using conditional formatting in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to change the colour of several cells on a sheet in excel 2007, what i need to do is for the cells to pick out a word entered within a sentence in each of those cells and then change colour. Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel 2010 pictured but 2007 almost identical. Here I'll highlight cells that contain the word 'bread'. Select the range of cells that you want to apply conditional formatting to. From the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting > New Rule...

[image: select range and enter conditional formatting]

Select 'Format only cells that contain' and change the options as shown below. Click the 'Format' button and add whatever format you want to see.

[image: set options]

Done:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the info it was brill and ill use on my laptop, but im sorry but my bad i made a mistake i need the info for PC which has excel 2003 not 07. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Same principle in 2003, but instead of going Home>Conditional Formatting you'll go Format>Conditional Formatting. Check out the guide near the bottom of this page: http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/conditional-formatting-in-excel/

Comment: Thanks for you patience and info, but i take it you cant do the same thing in 2003 as the later versions. i know how to get to the conditional format box but it only gives two options "cell value is" and "formula is"

Comment: OK sure, you can use a formula like this: `=if(substitute(a1, "bread", "")=a1,0,1)` ...that compares the cell value with the cell value after substituting the word 'bread'. If there's a difference, then the word 'bread' is present, and the formula evaluates to 1, rather than 0, and the conditional formatting is applied. By the way, in this example I reference cell A1... you should reference the first cell in your selected range (the range that you're applying conditional formatting to).

Comment: Thanks that worked but also picked up a few other blank cells but worked thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about the blank cells but one of these expanded formulas will likely overcome it: `=IFERROR(IF(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "bread", "")=A1,0,1),0)`
or, alternatively:
`=IF(A1="",0,IF(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "bread", "")=A1,0,1))`

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed after having a lil play Thank you for all your help =IF(SUBSTITUTE(D4, "proform", "")=D4,1,0)

Comment: Cool, good stuff :-)